# Intuition behind regularization of non-coercive variational inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-analysis

I am looking into the theory of non-coercive variational inequalities and I came accross the following approximation techinique:

Fix an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ and let $K \subset V$ be a closed and convex set containing the origin. Consider the variational inequality to find $u \in K$:

$$ a(u, v - u) \ge (f , v-u)_H \qquad \forall v \in K, \qquad (*) $$

where $a(\cdot, \cdot): H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a given *non coercive* bilinear form and $f \in H$.

The idea is now to approximate $(*)$ with a sequence of nonlinear equations: for $\lambda > 0$ consider the problem to find $u_{\lambda} \in H$ such that:

$$ a(u_{\lambda},v) + \frac{1}{\lambda}(u_{\lambda}, P_{K}v)_H = (f,v)_H \qquad \forall v \in H, \qquad (**) $$

where $P_K : H \rightarrow H$ is the orthogonal projection onto $K$. It is claimed that $u_{\lambda} \rightarrow u$ in $H$ as $\lambda \rightarrow 0$.

Rather than a proof of the claim (which I am not sure to be correct in this precise form), I am looking for an intuition behind the technique: why should we *expect* a similar type of converges as the coefficient in front of the nonlinear term explodes?
When dealing with similar questions for equalities, there is the advantage that we can subtract the formulations and look for estimates, which here we don't have.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $a$? Also ( ** ) looks strange. If $a=0$ and $K$ is the unit ball then ( * ) has solutions but the solutions of ( ** ) explode.

Comment: I was thinking about a non-negativity assumption of $a$, but this does not exclude your example...

Comment: How do you see that $(*)$ has solutions if $a=0$?

Comment: If $K$ is the unit ball then $u=f/\|f\|$ should be a solution.

Comment: Of course, youìre right, thank you. And why the ones of $(**)$ explode? I am sorry I can't see that.

Comment: ( ** ) has no solutions if $f\ne0$: Two addends are linear in $v$, the third involving $P_K$ is not, which forces $u_\lambda=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To long for a comment, and also to explain my comments above a bit.

---

For symmetric and coercive $a$, problem ( * ) is equivalent to
$$
\min_{u\in K} \frac12 a(u,u) - f(u).
$$
The constraint can be penalized by introducing a term that penalized the violation of the constraint
$$
\min_{u\in H} \frac12 a(u,u) - f(u) + \frac1{2\lambda}\|u - P_K(u)\|_H^2.
$$
This can be differentiated to yield something like ( ** ), but not equal to your suggestion  ( ** ).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now we might ask ourselves in which case such penalization  yields a way to approximate the solution of a variational inequality governed by a non-coercive bilinear form.